# Area navigation settings not responding

Tags: 2010, navigation

the problem I have, is that one of my site's area navigation settings page doesn't respond at all after entering it (I can't do any action). I saw few people with similar problem, but for them, at least, the problem was appearing only with while working with few particular nodes. So what I want to ask, what could be the causes and is there a way to fix this issue without redoing all the nodes? Or how could I diagnose the problem, because ULS didn't helped me at all.

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors if you enter (if you can) into the IE (F12) Developer Tools?

Comment: Not possible, developer tools doesn't respond to after entering areanavigationsettings.aspx page

Comment: Which version of IE do you use? Have you tried other browsers as well?

Comment: I have tried IE11 and Chrome, both works that way.